# Isolate part of string with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm currently making a script in Bash to make my life slightly easier at work.
I'm trying to isolate the host name from my `nslookup` call, but I'm having some issues.

The output from `nslookup` is `1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa name = nuc3.homenet.no` and I'm trying to match and save only the `nuc3` part of the string and save it in a variable, by capturing `nuc3` and replacing the whole string with the captured group.

```
NSLOOKUP=$(nslookup 10.0.0.1) 
NUC=$(echo ${NSLOOKUP} | sed -E 's/.*?(nuc\d+).*/\1/'
```

`\d+` is predominantly because there are several machines named the same way with numbers ranging from 1-10.

The output from `sed` would just default to printing the original string, so I'd something sketchy is going on. I've successfully used the same method to isolate strings earlier with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` doesn't support `\d`. Just use `[0-9]` and also match a space before `nuc` to avoid false matches:

```
echo '1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa name = nuc3.homenet.no' | sed -E 's/.* (nuc[0-9]+).*/\1/'
```

```
nuc3
```

Comment: That explains my issues. Worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not this ?

```
echo '1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa name = nuc3.homenet.no' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | tr -d -c '[a-zA-Z0-9.\n]'
```

Or also this :

```
echo '1.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa name = nuc3.homenet.no' | grep -o -P  '[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[.][a-zA-Z]+[.][a-zA-Z]+'
```